# Ktor Login Session cookie

Tags: kotlin, authentication, ktor

I am working on a login project using ktor. I am currently using the old method with session

```
    install(Sessions) {
    cookie<LoginSession>(
        "login_session",
        SessionStorageMemory()
    ){
        cookie.path = "/"
        cookie.extensions["SameSite"] = "lax"
        val secretSignKey = hex("000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f")
        transform(SessionTransportTransformerMessageAuthentication(secretSignKey))

    }

}
```

This code is the final one,so if i remove the sessionmanager and secretsignkey, it will show in plain text it's value
The rest is simple, i am routing a get /login to show the form, and a post /validate to validate the data entered by user, then if all is ok i just set the session. The problem is that i can see the session value using inspect element -> application->cookie and i can change it's value being able to login as any user , by just knowing it's id (in the session i am storing the user id). And on the expire column it does not say sesssion. What am I doing wrong?
P.S: I've read the docs for authentication feature but I want to keep this simple idea with sessions.

Comment: As a value for `login_session` cookie I see something like `c3b41b8ccba114c0d389a57144547735%2Ff78fe1f40922231a928660db9dd6b267bb6ae69bee6d8a8020c8d1c9d3f1d6c1`. Could you please update your question to provide a concrete example of how a user can change a cookie value and share a definition for `LoginSession` class?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman you see that string because you use SessionStorageMemory, if you remove that line you will see the plain text

Answer (score 0):

Use a Ktor [session transformer](https://ktor.io/docs/transformers.html) to transform (authenticate or encrypt) the cookie contents.

Example:

```kotlin
// REMEMBER! Change ALL the digits in those hex numbers and store them safely
val secretEncryptKey = hex("00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff")
val secretAuthKey = hex("02030405060708090a0b0c")
cookie<TestUserSession>(cookieName) {
    transform(SessionTransportTransformerEncrypt(secretEncryptKey, secretAuthKey))
}
```